# What is the meaning of $('.myclass').show().addClass('selected')?

Tags: jquery

I check the jQuery document on show() function at https://api.jquery.com/show/#show. It only said show() is used to show the specific element, but does not indicate it will return a value. Why addClass can be invoked on the return value of show?

Comment: The document defined returns type: jQuery, https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery

Comment: @HoangHieu, thank you very much. I read the doc and it describes "Many jQuery methods return the jQuery object itself, so that method calls can be chained" and "In API calls that return jQuery, the value returned will be the original jQuery object unless otherwise documented by that API."

Comment: It's an interesting question and weird that it actually works, but why would you ever do it that way? .. It's super confusing.. I would never code like that..

Comment: @Gass, This is not my code. I am studying others' codes and find this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

First part as you know `$('.myclass')` is a selector and returns elements (in this case elements containing myclass class).
show() will run the show() function on the selected elements and then return the selected items again so you can run any other function that is available for the selected elements.